# CKEditor 5 image upload error in React Js

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I tried the official upload command, but it's not working.

**This is the CKEditor part**

```
<CKEditor
  placeholder="write"
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  data={this.state.body}
  /*  config={{ckfinder: {
    // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
    uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
  }}} */                      
  onReady={(editor) => {
    // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
    console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
  }}
  onChange={(event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    this.setState({ body: data });
  }}
/>
```

After inserting this, I can upload a picture, but a message pops up with the following:

[image: This message pop up]

The console displays this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
> example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json:1

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: which version of CKEditor you are using? did you set the cors policy?

Comment: CKEditor 5.yesi set

Comment: It doesn't make sense, please double-check your cors policy here is a [link](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)  and here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/10321531).

Comment: I checked.I already setup cors policy

Comment: Add the `options` below uploadUrl: `options: { resourceType: 'Images' }`

Comment: Why are you trying to post to the example.com domain?

Comment: @diedu  how it should be correct way

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to upload the images to the url `"https://example.com/...` which, as far as I can tell, is just a default value for the upload configuration, but not meant as a proper URL for file-uploads.

According to the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html#server-side-configuration-2):

> To use this upload adapter, you must provide a server–side application
> that will handle the uploads and communicate with the editor, as
> described in the following sections.

This means that you need to have access to a server side application to upload your images onto.

If you have that, you can follow the configuration guide [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html#configuration) to set the `uploadUrl` to the correct address.
If you don't have access to a server-side application, you will need to obtain it if you want to use the uploading functionality. A simple suggestion may for example be [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation), which is a Software as a Service provider that can act as an endpoint for your uploaded files. It should be a whole lot easier than trying to create a server app on your own.

Comment: I haven't a server-side application. How I build it? otherwise, I haven't idea about  use uploading functionality

Comment: @AnushkaPraveen Check out Cloudinary, see if you can make sense of that. I've updated the answer to explain it a bit. Otherwise that's a way too big topic for a question here, and honestly a whole profession.